# json schema validation - conditional properties not validating correctly

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json object formatted like below

```
{
    "notificationType": "Directed",
    "userPaths": [
        "organization.SsoId"
    ],
    "id": "d15f83f3-f393-4839-ae72-a1e732219bb4",
}
```

I have a schema validation as per the below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "notificationType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "userPaths": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "notificationType",
    "userPaths",
    "id"
  ]
}
```

I need to validate that if notificationType value is `Directed` then userPaths needs to have a minimum of one item

trying this

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "notificationType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "userPaths": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "notificationType",
    "userPaths",
    "id"
  ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "notificationType": {
            "const": "Directed"
          }
        },
        "required": ["notificationType"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "userPaths": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "minItems": 1
          }
        },
        "required": ["userPaths"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and testing at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/AEMI0Py8 with changing the value and removing the items from the userPaths array it still says this is valid object.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to where I have gone wrong and what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: ` "then ": {` here, do we supposed to have an extra space?

Comment: @JishanShaikh having removed the additional space, the result is still the same

Comment: Issue resolved at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/UMLxjgnk